# WCF error and exception handling

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-4.0

In WCF service I would like to handle errors and exception using custom fault.

I need to be able in case of the error return

CustomFault with Description and Error code

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a DataContract class for your custom fault.  It sounds like at a minimum in your case, this class will have an Error Code property and a Description property.  Next, in your Service Contract, you'll need to decorate any service operations that can raise this fault with the FaultContract attribute.  For example:

```
[OperationContract()]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyCustomFault))]
ResponseDataContract SomeServiceOperation(RequestDataContract request);
```

Finally, in your service implementation, you'll need to throw the custom fault as a FaultExcepton.  For example:

```
try
{
  DoStuff();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw new FaultException<MyCustomFault>(new MyCustomFault
                                              {
                                                Description = "Oh No!",
                                                ErrorCode = 1234
                                              });
}
```